# how does retailer connect to Google wallet acount in a third party website?

Tags: android-pay

I'm a developer of a website that enable retailers to interact with rheir customers at events. the way it works is that the retailer selles a product on my website, the costumer buys it on my website, i'm the common thread. i want to offer the consumers to pay with google wallet. the question is how does the retailer coonect his google wallet business acount to the button which will be on my website? can it be done with the email he has opened his google wallet business acount? Thanks! Amitai.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the seller doesn't have access to any information about the customer. You need to be able to obtain the `JWT` or `Merchant Key` from the original retailer to be able to perform sale on your own website. Only tool you have available to pass information around is the `JWT`. There are several security and process issues related to this.